# Cubic function growth

Tags: cubics

Hopefully this question isn't too simple for this site.

I'm doing a CompSci algorithms course, and trying to understand various growth rates.

A function with cubic complexity such as the [3Sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM) problem seems to work like this. Every time you double the input size, the running time multiplies by 8. My sample data looks like this:

```
1024, 50.94
512,  6.33
256,  0.8
128,  0.10
64,   0.01
```

Obviously this applies to regular math:

```
3^3 = 27
6^3 = 216
12^3 = 1728
```

and 27 * 8 = 216, 216 * 8 = 1728.

I've been trying to figure this out so I can understand it, but my Math isn't very great and I'm not sure what to Google, so I'm not having much look.

Why does a cubic function work like this, with running time multiplying by 8 every time the input doubles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define $f(x) = x^3$. Then $f(2x) = (2x)^3 = 2^3 x^3 = 8x^3$. The ratio $\dfrac{f(2x)}{f(x)} = \dfrac{8x^3}{x^3} = 8$.

Comment: And now I feel like an idiot, pretty obvious solution. Didn't think to look at it as a function. Many thanks!

Comment: I know from experience when you start coding you tend to think in algorithms instead of functions and that can sometimes hide what is going on.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind as I continue learning algorithms!